# Connect Windows Mobile 6 emulator to internet on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows-mobile

I have a slight problem... I need to connect the Windows Phone 6 emulator to internet. That requires Virtual PC 2007. However, VPC 2007 is not supported for Windows 7. When I try to run the setup program Windows tells me the program is blocked due to compatibility issues. Running the setup file in Compatibility Mode didn't help either.

What to do ? o_O

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've used the method described on [this blog](http://www.brianpeek.com/post/2009/05/02/windows-virtual-pc-and-the-microsoft-device-emulator.aspx) dozens of times.  It has workaround instructions for 32 and 64 bit Windows 7.

Comment: Yargh, I tried this yesterday but could not get any network connection. Since you suggested the same I figured I could try again in case I did anything wrong yesterday. 

Well, the steps in Windows were the same but this time I noticed a notification on the WP6 telling me I had to connect =)

Comment: This is not working on my machine. I am not able to install the needed service to my lan device. I sunk the whole workday into this and NOONE konws a decent documentation on how to connect the freaking emulator to a lan device!

Comment: Did you get any error messages during the process?  The process should work regardless if you're using a wired or wireless LAN.  One thing that isn't intuitive is you have to click an alert and specify if connecting to the Internet or Work before the connection will actually work.  The notification appears in the task bar 5-15 seconds after you select the network adapter inside the emulator.